# Error using plot function - matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I am trying to use `plot` function using the following code

```
fid = fopen('data1.dat');
out = textscan(fid,'%s%f%f','delimiter','\t');
fclose(fid);
col1=out{1};
col2=out{2};
m=col1;
m1=col2;
disp(m1);
plot(m,m1);
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Error using plot
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Error in sample (line 10)
plot(m,m1);
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here with this code.

Comment: Your col1 and col2 arrays are still cell array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you take the wrong cell: `col1=out{1};` was a cell array with strings. But you can't plot strings...

This is what you get by `textscan`

```
out{1} = {'te' 'st' 'xt'};
out{2} = [ 12.3400
           23.5400
           34.9000 ];
out{3} = [ 12.3400
           23.5400
           34.9000 ]/2;
```

See [Matlab: textscan example](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btg0kes)

So you can plot col 3 over 2 for example. If you want to plot over your col 1 you can do this:

```
plot(1:length(out{1}),out{2});
set(gca,'XTick',1:length(out{1}),'XTickLabel',out{1})
```

[image]